# Node issues appending to a file at a position using a WriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am working on a small project where I write large amounts of data to a file (well 10+mb, okay it's not that much). And I want to write to my output everytime I get data, incase my program crashes or whatever, I don't want to persist my data in memory then write when I am done.

My issue is that I want to write to a particular position in my file everytime, an example might be I want to write to a valid JSON structure. IE I start with my file containing an array '[]' and everytime I get data I want to append an object into that array in my file, so now I want '[{something : 'great'}]' in my file. The next time I write I want '[{somethingElse : 'yes'}, {something : 'great'}]'.

So everytime I want to append some data to a position in the file, and I could be writing 10 to 50 times a second.

I am attempting to do this using fs.createWriteStream, but everytime I specify a start position I get some random encoding issues, and I cannot tell what is going on. This works fine if I do not specify a start and the encoding is not messed up, but it of course does not end up with the correct looking file.

Here is my basic code

```
function JSONOutputFormatter (outputFileName, counter) {
    var counter = counter,
        outputFileName = outputFileName,
        options = { encoding : 'utf8', start : Buffer.byteLength('[', 'utf8'), flags: 'a'},
        writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFileName + '.json', options);

    var appendToFile = function (toAppend) {
        writeStream.write(toAppend);
    };

    return {
        open   : function () {
            fs.appendFileSync(outputFileName + '.json', '[]');
        },
        append : function (data) {
           appendToFile(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
        close  : function () {
            writeStream.end();
        }
    };
}
```

My problem is that whenever data is being appended I am losing the closing ']'.

So my question is o I need to specify the end option position to write at everytime, IE the byte length of the data I am writing? And if so is there a better way to do that then create a new WriteStream everytime, write does not accept the ending position.

Also is there potentially a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible alternative: just keep a file containing newline-delimited JSON objects. That way you just do something like `fs.appendFileSync('foo', JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n');` to add a new record.

Then when you want to read the entire (or even partial) contents, just do something like (you could do this async just as easily):

```
var data = JSON.parse('[' + fs.readFileSync('foo', 'utf8').replace(/\n/g, ',') + ']');
```

Comment: Good suggestion, this would be much simpler, but I would really like to be able to read the file off the file system without having to manipulate the data.

Comment: The only other solution I can think of, would be to open the file everytime, find the length of the contents and then do a positional write. Though I am worried about the performance of this and the cost of all the IO if this is happening very rapidly.